# Dapper multiple objects from one row

Tags: c#, dapper

I have one row coming from the database

```
select "John" Name, 
       "Male" Gender,
       20 Age,
       "Rex" PetName,
       "Male" PetGender,
       5 PetAge
       // ... many more ...
```

Using Dapper, I'd like to pull this row into two objects:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    // ... many more ...
}    
class Pet
{
    public string PetName { get; set; }
    public string PetGender { get; set; }
    public int PetAge { get; set; }
    // ... many more ...
}
```

Note: there is no hierarchical relationship here, I'm simply trying to map one database row into two (or more) objects.

How can I do this using dapper?

- I know I can do this by returning a dynamic and mapping each object manually, which is painful as in my scenario we have a large number of columns.  I'd rather not do this.  (And no, it can't be redesigned to require less columns.)

What I've tried:

- I've looked into `QueryMultiple<Person,Pet>`, but it assumes I am running multiple queries. In my real-life scenario, this is a very expensive query, and I'd like to just run it once.
- I've also looked into returning `Query<Person,Pet,Tuple<Person,Pet>>`, but this requires an `Id` column, here there's no hierearchical relationship or `Id`s. I just want to take a single row and map it to multiple columns.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You were pretty close to solution with the `Query` method. If you don't have an `Id` column, then you can provide a `splitOn` argument:

```
connection.Query<Person, Pet, Tuple<Person, Pet>>(sql, 
    (person, pet) => Tuple.Create(person, pet), splitOn: "PetName");
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Even when I supply `splitOn`, I still get `ArgumentException: When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id. Parameter name: splitOn`

Comment: that's odd. you might have to show us the exact sql query and the code. not likely but maybe your splitOn field exists in the first type as well, and you mean to include it in the second type, by any chance?

Comment: You're right, when I use it with this toy scenario, it works fine. I'll have to dig in and figure out where my stuff is going wrong in my real code.

Comment: Here's what I found: even for the sample I gave in my question, it looks like it matters what value I give to `splitOn`, and it's related to column order.  Depending on which value I give, different columns come out null.  For example, if I use your query and `splitOn = "PetGender"`, then `PetName` is null.  It seems to have to do with column order, because when I return the columns in a different order, different fields are null.  I don't see any obvious pattern.

Comment: the logic is pretty simple really. It looks at the columns sequentially. In your example query, if you say `splitOn="PetName"`, it will use the first 3 columns to build the Person, and the rest to build the Pet. If Person has more properties/fields that are not in the first 3 columns, then those props will remain at their default value(e.g null).

Comment: Wow! Is this documented anywhere? It does not make this very clear on Dapper's site [http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/].  It all makes sense now, thank you!

Comment: The best documentation, in my opinion, is the [Tests.cs](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Tests/Tests.cs).

Comment: Updated documentation link https://github.com/mhart/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Tests/Tests.cs