# how to return tuple of primitive data types in dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I have been using dapper for one of my projects and in one case I wanted to return a tuple of primitive data types. (only a single row) Since I used dapper, I really would like to use dapper for this case also. I checked these links but couldn't find a solution

[Can I map a result to Tuple in Dapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867432/can-i-map-a-result-to-tuple-in-dapper)

[Dapper multiple objects from one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755061/dapper-multiple-objects-from-one-row)

[Using Dapper to map more than 5 types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202584/using-dapper-to-map-more-than-5-types)

This is what my code looks like,

```
Using(_dbTransaction = _dbConnection.BeginTransaction()){

     var command = new CommandDefinition(
                "SELECT ID1,ID2 " +
                "FROM table " +
                "WHERE ID0 = @ID",
                new {ID = 34},_dbTransaction); //34 is just a number

    var dataSet   = _dbConnection.QueryFirst<Tuple<uint, decimal>>(command);

    //assign the retrieved values to properties of orderItem (orderItem is a passed object as a parameter)
    orderItem.Id = dataSet.item1;
    orderItem.ContainerPrice = dataSet.item2; 

}
```

but this would generate an exception

> {"A parameterless default constructor or one matching signature (System.UInt32 Id, System.Decimal ContainerPrice) is required for System.Tuple`2[[System.UInt32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] materialization"}

It would be a great help if can suggest a method or point out where I went wrong

Comment: From the error code being thrown... It sounds like you need to provide a default method signature.  Then the parameterized version of the method should work... given your logic checks out

Comment: @Chef_Code did you mean by default method signature? Is it QueryFirstOrDefault<>() ?

Comment: That is what I would eliminate first.  Provide a default signature... then go from there.  Yes, `QueryFirstOrDefault<>()` or the method your using `QueryFirst<Tuple<uint, decimal>>()` no parameter.  You can still use your overloaded version... the default just needs to be available

Comment: hover over `var` in front of `command`... Does the compiler think that `command` is a `Tuple<uint, decimal>>`?

Comment: Yes it is, dataSet(var) is a Tuple<uint, decimal>. And I also tried the method QueryFirstOrDefault<>() but it too doesn't work same exception

Comment: The answer to [How to use generic and Nullable<T> types in Dapper for materialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904081/how-to-use-generic-and-nullablet-types-in-dapper-for-materialization) might help

Comment: not dataSet.... the `command`

Comment: No it is not, command is a CommandDefinition

Comment: You need to explicitly map the `Tuple<uint, decimal>>` something like appending the following to the end of your query `.Select(
    row => Tuple.Create((uint)row.ID, (decimal)row.VALUE))`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use a Tuple, you can try this:

```
    [Test]
    public void TupleTest()
    {
        var result = _connection.Query<int, decimal, Tuple<int, decimal>>
            ("select 1 as Id, 12.99 as ContainerPrice", Tuple.Create, splitOn: "*")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.That(result.Item1, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(result.Item2, Is.EqualTo(12.99));
    }
```

You can also avoid Tuples, and use a dynamic:

```
    [Test]
    public void DynamicTest()
    {
        var result = _connection.Query<dynamic>
            ("select 1 as Id, 12.99 as ContainerPrice")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(result.ContainerPrice, Is.EqualTo(12.99));
    }
```